# what are the differences between Workflow and Buildflow [Jenkins]?

Tags: jenkins

**Explanation:**

My question is mostly as the title says. I installed them both to see the differences, but from what I see they have some options that differenciate them, but they mostly do the same thing?

I tried also reading the descriptions, http://jenkins-ci.org/content/workflow-plugin-10 and https://www.cloudbees.com/sites/default/files/juc_sfo_oct_14-_workflow.pdf and https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin

**What would be the major differences?** Maybe it's my English understanding, but they really look like about the same to me (I'm already familiar with the Buildflow and I don't see what the Workflow has to offer more).

**My guess:**

I'd say one of the major difference would be that with the workflow, using the DSL you can do many things which would require to call others jobs using the Buildflow?

Example : Sending an email, do script, send another email

Buildflow : Needs to call at least 2 jobs

Workflow : Can do all of this in the DSL

Comment: The ability to resume a job... if you do not have complex build flows that take a really long time to execute then it probably will not matter to you.. and if you do then you'll know it is a HUGE deal

Comment: From the build-plugin page  ... "You probably would be interested by https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin as a possible alternative."    Are they implying that build-flow is being superseded?  What is the takeaway from this statement?

Comment: Workflow has a snippet generator, which is useful.